# Display video stored in SD card in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-sdcard

I want to display all the videos stored inside my SD card in a GridView. I have followed [this tutorial](https://gypsynight.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/how-to-show-all-video-file-stored-in-your-sd-card-in-a-listview/) and changed it to suit my need. Below is my code for `getview()` inside my `CustomAdapter` class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        View listItemRow;
        listItemRow = LayoutInflater.from(vContext).inflate(R.layout.sd_card_list_item, parent, false);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView)listItemRow.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        ImageView thumbImage = (ImageView)listItemRow.findViewById(R.id.videocapture);
        videoColumnIndex = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        videoCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        txtTitle.setText(videoCursor.getString(videoColumnIndex));
        videoColumnIndex = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);
        videoCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int videoId = videoCursor.getInt(videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
        Cursor videoThumbnailCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID+ "=" + videoId, null, null);

        if (videoThumbnailCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            thumbPath = videoThumbnailCursor.getString(videoThumbnailCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));
        }
        thumbImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(thumbPath));
        thumbImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(VideoStoredInSDCardActivity.this,"Video Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(VideoStoredInSDCardActivity.this,SampleVideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return listItemRow;

}
```

The issue I am facing is that I am getting the **same thumbnail image**(1st Video thumbnail) for all my video.

What is wrong in the above code?

Also, how can I get the path of the video file user clicked inside my `onClickListener`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see this example http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/12/android-play-video-from-sd-card.html

Comment: @VishalThakkar, Thanks! The example given above worked after few changes.

Answer (score 0):

you are always getting path for first position with this videoThumbnailCursor.moveToFirst()

you need to maintain position in your getView method according to the position